# Tree recursion in Swift

Tags: swift, recursion

I was reviewing some recursive tree functions, but I'm a little confused on the return `||`, what condition is the return testing?

```
func search(node: Node?, searchValue: Int) -> Bool {
    
    if node == nil {
        return false
    }
    
    if node?.data == searchValue {
        return true
    } else {
        return search(node: node?.left , searchValue: searchValue) || search(node: node?.right, searchValue: searchValue)
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html

Comment: You should check the link provided by pawello and learn about other operators too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement is recursively calling the `search` function with the left subtree and the right subtree.  Note that `search` returns a `Bool` indicating if the tree contains the value being searched for.

Because the *or* operator `||` *short circuits*, the right subtree will only be searched if the `search` failed to find the item in the left subtree.  When the search for the left subtree returns `true`, then `search` immediately returns `true` without searching the right subtree.  If both recursive calls to `search` return `false`, then the search really has failed and `false` is returned (that is `false || false` is `false`).

So, that return statement is doing the following:

```
if searchValue is in the left subtree {
    return true
} else if the searchValue is in the right subtree {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is checking if the `left` OR(`||`) `right` node is either `nil` or `data` is equal to the `searchValue`. If either of those conditions satisfy it returns `true`. If both are `false` that results in `false`.